# Drugs@FDA Endpoint - Why is the openFDA field missing from some applications

Tags: api, openfda

I'm building a search form using the openFDA API starting with the Drugs@FDA endpoint. In my attempts to find a consistent method and identifiable field to search for drugs I have noticed some inconsistencies not talked about in the project documentation.

Question: What is the openFDA field and why is it not included in every application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Some extra questions would be:

2. Is there a unique identifier for discontinued drugs besides products.marketing_status?
3. Is there a way to search with the NOT operator? example: Can I search for products where marketing_status != discontinued ?

Answer (score 0):

openFDA field shows the data that is cross populated from other datasets. It is missing in some of the APIs because the data in those APIs
is not harmonized with data from other datasets.

Comment: Hey RKG! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately that didn't really answer my question.

My question asked "why is it not included in every application". You referred to it being absent from other API's. An application isn't an API, and application refers to an "application" to the FDA. Think of it like a job application. An application can be for a new drug, an updated drug, multiple drugs, or only a single drug. Hope this helps.